# How to add a background image to jquery mobile button

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an image folder containing two button images.(normal_button.png and button_pressed.png) .i want to include them to my project.how can i edit my css file?should i need to create a new css file? and how i use two button images to represent button pressed state and normal button state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
 <style>
    .normal_button {/*background: green;*/background: url('normal_button.png');}
    .buton_pressed {/*background: red;*/background: url('buton_pressed.png');}
 </style>
 </head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="form">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#queue" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="flip">Queue</a>
        <h1>Form</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"> 
    <a href="" class="normal_button" id="btn" data-role="button">Button</a>         
    </div>
    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"></footer>
</div> 

</body>
<script>        
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("normal_button")){
        $(this).removeClass("normal_button");
        $(this).addClass("buton_pressed");
        return;
    }if($(this).hasClass("buton_pressed")){
        $(this).removeClass("buton_pressed");
        $(this).addClass("normal_button");
        return;
    }
  });    
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shuold add your normal_button.png  adress image in btn-up section of your css file (but for your favorit theme for example /* A) and button_pressed.png adress in btn-hover and btn-down and btn-active section of your css file(so for your favorit theme).
You should find    /* Button up */    in your favorit theme and add your image adress down off background color definatin and up off border-color.
For example look at this:

```
/* Button up */
.ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn,
html .ui-bar-a .ui-btn,
html .ui-body-a .ui-btn,
html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-btn,
html head + body .ui-btn.ui-btn-a,
```